# Color Contrast Customization in Web Design

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, accessibility

How do I do the color color customization in HTML5? Examples can be found at http://perkins.org/ whereby they have a color contrast option on the top of their page.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, how this works is.. You attempt to do it your self if you are stuck you post your code sample and we help you resolve the issue. Best of luck!

Comment: Use CSS. http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: They're probably switching style sheets. See e.g. [Javascript: Change CSS File Dynamically + Cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12229413)

Comment: Many more results when Googling ` css switch javascript stackoverflow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, mark all the elements you want to change as class "contrast" and then change the color and the background color:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('contrast');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.color = newcolor;
  elements[i].style.background = newbackground;
}
```

Comment: If this solves your issue, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark on your left as it will promote user "csander".

Comment: Thank you so much! I truly appreciated the works that you guys have done! It saves me a lot of time trying to figure out the process.