# Dynamically Changing theme of a page using css and javascript, but after refresh the selected theme is not retained

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

I am trying to change the page theme using javascript dynamically and passing the URL of the style sheet. 
whenever I refresh the page, reload the page, go back etc. It changes back to the default css

Comment: maybe this one helps [Stack Javascript: Change CSS File Dynamically + Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229413/javascript-change-css-file-dynamically-cookie)

Comment: function changeStyle(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) {
    var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);
    var newlink = document.createElement("link");
    newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    newlink.setAttribute("href", cssFile);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink)
}

Comment: I am passing the css url in the button